# Karate API compare 2 jsons by ignore partiuclar fields comparision

Tags: karate

I have 2 json which i am trying to compare using karate api on those jsons some of the fields values keep changing,so would like to ignore ignore those fields comparison

From the above json's i need to ignore comparison of maxScore and score value and compare the rest of the json

Comment: please read the documentation for `match contains`: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#match-contains